# Is there a way to channel some HTTP server events into a single javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, httpexception

I have a C# webserver which provides some html/js/css and images to a browser-based client.

I create the page dynamically using javascript, filling images and divs while receiving messages from a websocket C# server.

Sometimes, I receive a message from the websocket and I try to access a resource in the webserver which might be protected.

I have some custom http server events for this (say, 406) because otherwise [the browser pops up a dialog box for digest auth login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159551/is-it-possible-to-use-digest-authentication-with-a-xmlhttprequest/13915068#13915068).

I was wondering whether there is a way to channel all 406 events into the same function, say

```
RegisterHttpEventHandler(406,myFunction);
```

I guess I could just wrap any request/dynamic load in try and catches, although I'd love a cleaner way of doing this.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the workflow which I implemented so far, and which works fine.

```
// Websocket definition
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://' + addressIP);
// Websocket receiver callback

conn.onmessage = function (event) {
        // my messages are json-formatted
        var mObj = JSON.parse(event.data);
        // check if we have something nice
        if(mObj.message == "I have got a nice image for you"){
        showImageInANiceDiv(mObj.ImageUrl);
        }
    };

// Dynamic load image
function showImageInANiceDiv(imgUrl )
{
    var imgHtml = wrapUrlInErrorHandler(imgUrl);
    $("#imageBox").html(imgHtml);
}    

// function to wrap everything in an error handler
function wrapUrlInErrorHandler(Url)
{
    return '<img src="' + Url + '" onerror="errorHandler(\''+ Url +'\');"/>';
}

// function to handle errors
function errorHandler(imgUrl)
{
     console.log("this guy triggered an error : "  + imgUrl);
}




//
```

Comment: Could you show us your socket connection code?

Comment: I edited my answer to add some code examples of what I am doing.

Comment: Thanks. So the image load returns a 406, and fails to call the `onerror` handler?

Comment: No. There are two issues: the onerror does not tell me what failed, so I have to make an XHR just to find it out. That's a minor thing. The other issue is that I'd like to have something like a document.onerror handler to avoid using the wrapUrlInErrorHandler function every time I have to put an image in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the onerror does not tell me what failed, so I have to make an XHR just to find it out. That's a minor thing

You could first try the XHR. If it fails, you know what happened, if it succeeds you can display the image from cache (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13920097/1048572)). And of course you also could make it call some globally-defined custom hooks for special status codes - yet you will need to call that manually, there is no pre-defined global event source.

> I'd like to have something like a document.onerror handler to avoid using the wrapUrlInErrorHandler function every time I have to put an image in the page

That's impossible. The `error` event ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/error), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197053(v=vs.85).aspx)) does not bubble, it fires directly and only on the `<img>` element. However, you could get around that ugly `wrapUrlInErrorHandler` if you didn't use inline event attributes, but [(traditional) advanced event handling](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html):

```
function showImageInANiceDiv(imgUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imgUrl;
    img.onerror = errorHandler; // here
    $("#imageBox").empty().append(img);
}
// function to handle errors
function errorHandler(event) {
     var img = event.srcElement; // or use the "this" keyword
     console.log("this guy triggered an "+event.type+": "  + img.src);
}
```

Comment: Don't call the wrapper 'ugly', he's particularly touchy :) Jokes apart, thanks for the thorough answer. I'll use your suggestion.